# Is it bad practice to use environment variables in rm -rf statements?

Tags: linux, shell

I was maintaining some shell scripts that we use for automated builds on our development server, when i moved a variable definition from on script file to another, along with several other lines of code. As a result, this line:

```
WEB=/home/server/web
```

got moved from that script file into another script file, and was no longer in the environment utilized by the first script file. Thus, later in the file,

```
rm -rf $WEB/*
```

got evaluated to the Linux user's dreaded command: `rm -rf /*`

My question is, would you consider using environment variables in this way bad practice or considered harmful? Something like the classic

```
if (foo)
    bar()
    bar2()
```

where the implications of removing the variable declaration are not immediately obvious, and can be surprising down the line? Or should i just be more careful when moving things like this around?

Comment: Something i just though of: If you are careful of where you put your / characters, you can reduce the potential for harm. E.g.
`WEB=/home/server/web/`, and then `rm -rf $WEB`. This isn't strictly equivalent, but is for most intents and purposes. Thus, if $WEB is not set by accident, the rm command does *nothing*, which is much better than removing everything.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really say it's "bad practice" but I will say that anytime you're doing an rm -rf in a script it's wrought with peril ;)

Typically what I'll do is create a directory called /tmp/todelete, them mv all the data I'm going to delete during my script there, then just wipe that directory every couple hours via a cron job.  That way if something goes haywire, I have time to catch it before the data is really dropped.

Comment: That's an interesting way to go, especially since `mv` operations are typically cheap (unless you are moving across physical drives). Kind of like the recycle bin or trash.

Comment: s/wrought/[fraught](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/74315)/ || die

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the assignment was actually (no `$`):

```
WEB=/home/server/web
```

If that was written in the script, then it wasn't an environment variable; it is perfectly legitimate to use it in any way that is appropriate, including in `rm -fr $WEB/*`.

If the assignment was not in the script, or only defaulted in the script, then it is more dangerous, but it is still legitimate to use it:

```
: ${WEB:=/home/server/web}

rm -fr $WEB/*
```

This means 'if the environment variable `$WEB` is set to a non-empty value, use it; otherwise use the value `/home/server/web`'.  This value of `$WEB` should be sanity checked, especially if `root` will run the script.  Note that a trailing blank in the value of `$WEB` could wreak unintended havoc.

However, it becomes a judgement call.  I'd probably not do it; environment variables used to remove stuff are too susceptible to accidental or deliberate abuse.  I would probably require the value passed as an argument to the script.  But it is not formally wrong to use an environment variable; it is just a bit dangerous.  If you've got good backups, it is not so dangerous, but beware `WEB=/` in the environment!

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to check if variables have values set (defensive programming)

For example

```
#!/bin/bash

#WEB=
WEB=/home/server/web

if [ -z "${WEB+X}" ]
then
  echo "\$WEB is unset"
elif [ -z "$WEB" ]
then
  echo "\$WEB is set but empty"
else
  echo "The value of \$WEB is $WEB"
  rm -rf $WEB/*
fi
```

Comment: Well, the variable was originally set within the same script, so that seems like a bit of overkill :P.

Comment: Agreed. It might be a good idea to check them for critical operations like `sudo rm -rf` though.  Might be an overkill for `ls $WEB`. :)

Answer (score 0):

In general using environment variables is a little dangerous, but as you've discovered they can be very dangerous in certain places.  One other source of danger is that the variables can be set arbitrarily in the shell by other programs if your forget to set/check them.

However you really need environment variables to do things using a shell like bash.  If you can avoid them in the "dangerous" places (`rm`, `chmod`, `chown`,...), so much the better.  In general, I think the best approach is to be more cautious when moving things around and using commands like `rm`.

Comment: Caution is always good around the `rm` command, especially if the `-r` and `-f` switches are involved :P.